# Trim text- when lot of space keys are entered at end

Tags: java, android, trim

I have a edit text field in which reason can be entered. But if a person enters all spaces in the reason how can I detect it. Is there a way when a person enters all spaces or nothing , i have to save the text the text as a simple "hiphen". My main question is how to trim those spaces coming at the end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The method trim() in String trims excess spaces on Strings.

```
String str = "Hello  ";
String str2 = str.trim();
```

str2 would equal "Hello".

As for detecting when a person enters all spaces - check the str.length() after you've ran str.trim().

Comment: It also trims all ASCII control characters; e.g. CR, NL and HT (tab).

Comment: It also trims *leading* ASCII white-space.

Answer (score 2):

You would be handling some events too..

like whenever the user clicks a button, you collect the text of your edit text.

For your need, there's a function:

```
String String.trim();
```

it removes all the spaces that are before and after your text (leading and trailing spaces)

to use it, do this:

```
String msg = editText.getText().toString();
msg = msg.trim();
if(msg.equals("")){
  msg = "-";
}
```

now 'msg' will be having a 'hyphen' in case user has entered nothing.

this is almost what @Laurence said..

Comment: @ognian I know that's a poor code. I was just trying to explain things to xydev in simplest way possible

Comment: Sorry! Just that someone could see it and start comparing against empty string every time he/she wants to check if the string is empty.

Comment: @xydev thanks! I just corrected it. weird typo!
@ognian I couldn't get u, sorry!