# error while parsing an integer

Tags: android, parsing

This is my **code :**

```
  TextView headerVal = (TextView) nextChild.findViewById(R.id.textView3); 
  String tt = ((String)headerVal.getText()).replaceAll(",",""); //it was 1,000 and it became 1000           
    int longueur = tt.length();
    String aux2 = (String) tt.substring(0,longueur - 2);
    int contenu = (int) Integer.parseInt(aux2);// here is the error "unable to  parse 1000 as an integer".
```

**PS:** it works on the emulator but i got this error on my phone

**Logcat**:

```
04-04 13:04:15.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31718): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-04 13:04:15.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31718): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '1 000' as integer

04-04 13:04:15.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31718):at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:433)

04-04 13:04:15.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31718):at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:422)

04-04 13:04:15.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31718):at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
04-04 13:04:15.210:E/AndroidRuntime(31718):at com.example.appui.BarGraphActivity.setColumnParts(BarGraphActivity.java:408)
04-04 13:04:15.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31718):at com.example.appui.BarGraphActivity.access$2(BarGraphActivity.java:282)
04-04 13:04:15.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31718):at com.example.appui.BarGraphActivity$Desired_pension.onStopTrackingTouch(BarGraphActivity.java:162)
```

Comment: What it is showing??Any error??

Comment: unable to  parse 1000 as an integer

Comment: @Sebastian didn't got your idea,details please

Comment: Probably a problem of [trimming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

Comment: why you are typecasting 'int' in last statement after parsing value in Integer ?

Comment: what is this statement returning exactly "String aux2 = (String) tt.substring(0,longueur - 2);"

Comment: @ManishL it's the same with or without
Subburaj because in the text view i had 1,000 & 2 letters so i used substring to use the number only

Answer (score 0):

Use [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) as below:

```
 DecimalFormat format =(DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance();
 format.applyPattern("#,###");
 try {
     integer = (Integer)format.parse(tt);
 } catch (ParseException e) {
     System.err.println(new Date()+": "+e.getMessage());
 }
```

Comment: Post your entire code, it works for me, must be something silly

Comment: can't post the whole code because it's too long but regarding the parse,it's the full code after that i use value i parsed for some operations

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test = ",100,0,0,";
        int newTest;
        test = test.replaceAll(",","");

        int longueur = test.length();
              // If the longueur length is greater than or equal to test.length() then it will return error, so put a check to see the longueur is not exceeding the test length.
        String aux2 = (String) test.substring(0,longueur - 2);

        newTest = Integer.parseInt(aux2);

        System.out.println(newTest);

    }
```

**Result 100, if longueur - 1 Returns 1000**

Answer (score 0):

You just use **trim** function after replace :-

```
String str2 = str.trim();
```

Above code remove all space into your string then convert string into integer:-

```
TextView headerVal = (TextView) nextChild.findViewById(R.id.textView3); 
String tt = ((String)headerVal.getText()).replaceAll(",",""); //it was 1,000 and it became 1000           

 String str2 = tt .trim();
int longueur = str2 .length();
```

Then do ur task what you want....

Comment: trim remove the spaces at the beginning or the end http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932163/removing-spaces-from-string

Comment: @user2137817 then u have to check this link also <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398360/trim-text-when-lot-of-space-keys-are-entered-at-end>   <http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29>